# WPF Databinding - Getter/Setter for intermediary object not getting hit

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

1. My WPF TextBox uses a class instance (called "SelectedDocument") as its datacontext. This class implements INOtifyPropertyChanged.
2. The SelectedDocument instance owns another object of type "CellContent" (named "Description"), exposed via a property.
3. CellContent also implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
4. The CellContent class has a string property ("TextValue") that can be bound to.
5. I'm binding the TextBox's Text property to that TextValue property. Like so:

   ```
   <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedDocument}" Text="{Binding Path=Description.TextValue" />
   ```

No issues with the databinding - it works both ways. But for that binding to work, WPF presumably has to hit the Description property in SelectedDocument every time to retreive the CellContent object:

```
public CellContent Description
{ get; set; }
```

(This property is more complicated in my code.) *Then* WPF can reach inside the actual CellContent object and get/set TextValue.

**The problem:** the Description property is never hit. It looks like WPF is bypassing it, and has created a direct connection to the TextValue property inside of the Description object. *I want to hit the Description getter and setters every time so that I can execute some extra code there.*

How do I do that?

Comment: Without a good [mcve], it's impossible to make any confident statement about what's happening. But it's perfectly natural that WPF will _not_ retrieve the `Description` property value unless that property value actually changes. As long as all that's changed is `Description.TextValue`, only the `TextValue` property would be retrieved. Given that, you need to ask a different question: how to address whatever broader goal it is you have that led you to this misguided design, where you expected a property value to be retrieved even when there's no reason for it to be.

Comment: Since we don't know what that broader goal is, we can't actually help you. So far, all we can do is tell you that the framework is working as expected and that it's _your_ expectation is flawed.

Comment: There isn't really much magic here to the underlying design: Description used to be a string property, and I used to bind straight to that. There was some extra code in that Description property that would get executed (every time data is fed back, the document is marked as Dirty). Now each piece of data is more than just a string, so it made sense to encapsulate all of it into a new class, and access that class through the old property. Except that it's not being hit anymore.

Comment: So my assumption (without know much about the internals of WPF databinding) is that the actual connection that's made (when compiling the BAML?) skips the Property in-between. Maybe I'm totally off-base. But if that's true, the question is what pattern to use to get around the problem (unexecuted code that used to execute). So Step 1: I'd like to understand what's happening, Step 2: I'd like to know how to work around what's happening.

Comment: Marking the `Description` object dirty could be done in the `TextValue` setter. But it sounds like you want the `SelectedDocument` marked dirty. It would be best to not expose the mutable underlying raw value in a way that can't be tracked, or `SelectedDocument` could just register a handler on `Description`. Keep an eye though towards tracking changes for Undo/Redo, Transactions etc.

Comment: _"Now each piece of data is more than just a string, so it made sense to encapsulate all of it into a new class"_ -- then why didn't you move the logic from the `Description` getter into the `TextValue` getter? Frankly, it's a design smell to have a getter perform anything _other_ than getting the value. I'm especially skeptical of the idea of using a _getter_ to detect when a document is "dirty" (i.e. has been written to/changed). But given that you started with that approach, at least being consistent in your refactor should avoid the issue you have.

Comment: Because the logic should be performed on the SelectedDocument class, and CellContents don't know about their owner so they can't affect it. Yet. (I might have to change that.) I guess I don't understand the design smell since C# properties are syntactic sugar around regular long-form accessors that I could code by hand. In my world, those have been performing additional stuff for a long time.

Comment: _Getting_ a property value does not inherently modify an object (such as a document). A "dirty" flag typically indicates that an object has been modified. Hence, setting a "dirty" flag when code _gets_ a property value is atypical at best, and just plain wrong at worst. It would be better to modify the flag when the property changes. And if you have a multi-layer design, the document itself should be subscribing to property-change notification in objects it depends on, and updating its "dirty" flag in response to _that_. Having your business logic rely on side-effects of the UI logic is wrong.

Comment: You ought to be able to remove _all_ of the UI logic and still have your business logic work exactly as it did before.

Comment: Right. It's set to dirty when the *Setter* is hit. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I expected the intermediate getters and setters to be hit (just the codepath, forget about NotifyPropertyChanged) as the databinding reaches into the CellContent. But it looks like that isn't the case. (If anybody can verify/clarify that part I'd be most grateful, I want to understand.) So - it looks like I have to indeed do all of the work suggested: CellContents get dirty via binding, the document itself audits their state or subscribes to a notification to know if it's dirty.

Comment: All of this is happening inside the model, btw. But of course the WPF frontend should affect the model's actual data, which then causes the model to mark its document as dirty.

Comment: _"I expected the intermediate getters and setters to be hit (just the codepath, forget about NotifyPropertyChanged) as the databinding reaches into the CellContent"_ -- please explain why you expect the _setter_ to be called, when all WPF needs to do it _get_ the property value.

Comment: Oh god. That's the brain fart. I just kept auto-setting breakpoints in the setters because... you know. Yeah, sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Document to be marked dirty whenever a child's property is changed, you could subscribe to the child's `PropertyChanged` event.

I'm assuming your CurrentDocument looks something like this.

```
public class Doc
{
    public Doc()
    {
        _description = new CellContent();
       // subscribe to changes in child
        _description.PropertyChanged += DescriptionChanged; 
    }

    private void DescriptionChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Write($"I'm a dirty dirty document. Property {e.PropertyName} has changed");
    }

    private CellContent _description;
    public CellContent Description
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.Write("I assure you this is called every time a getter of the child properties is called");
            return _description;
        }
        // If you have a setter, don't forget to -= unsubscribe and resubscribe += after changing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for indulging my stupidity above. I'll mark this as correct because... well, that's how you should do it, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to to raise `PropertyChanged` event for Description every time when you change `TextValue` property.

Comment: Hmm, how would I do that? Everything is  initiated straight from the XAML via databinding.

Comment: Well, basically what NPras said :)